# NSRangeException when deleting UITableView row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I"m creating an alarm app.In that the home screen `tableview` while swiping left the row has to get deleted. i'm using the following code.But the app crashes throwing an exception error.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:

(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        [self.loadRemainderArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:Terminating app due to uncaught exception '`NSRangeException`', reason: `-[NSMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array`

Comment: That's because as the error says, your `loadRemainderArray` is empty and you are trying to remove an object from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is you are getting the error is because your array is empty. The reasons it may be empty is:

1. You did not init the array:

   ```
   self.loadRemainderArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]
   ```
2. You never added an object to your array:

   ```
   [self.loadRemainderArray addObject:yourObject];
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The array you're trying to remove the object from is empty or not initialised. You should protect your code as follows:

```
if (indexPath.row < [self.loadRemainderArray count])
[self.loadRemainderArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

This doesn't solve your problem though - you need to find the root cause to understand why the array is empty or nil

Answer (score 0):

This line lead to your crash.`[self.loadRemainderArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`. Because you try to remove object from empty array. Just write this code.

```
if (self.loadRemainderArray.count > indexPath.row)
    [self.loadRemainderArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I think, You have done mistake in some other place, so that array is empty in this method. Check with `loadRemainderArray` access in your code.

Answer (score 0):

There might be any of below two reason you getting this exception.

1. You forgot to [NSMutableArray alloc] init] your array. And Without initialising added objects to it.
   self.loadRemainderArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
2. You have not added any objects to this array.

Comment: When this `commitEditingStyle:` delegate will call? How do you say he didn't add object to array? what is diff between your answer and Abdullah Shafique's answer?

Comment: I just added little more description to first point. And I just told possibilities for this exception.

Comment: Did you tell about ` Without initialising added objects to it` this point? tell now, what you add as extra point ?